# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I`m MAC user and
I have been struggling with this error. 
I search this error, now I just can't find solutions.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at GradeBook.inputGrades(GradeBook.java:53)
at GradeBookTest.main(GradeBookTest.java:12)
```

It is Not a problem of the variable, 
and the code written As recorded in the book .

Comment: Can you provide the code which throws the exception?

Comment: The code has a call to `nextInt`, which means it's expecting a number.  You're probably entering something that isn't a number.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 'while (input.hasNext())
  {
   grade = input.nextInt();
   total += grade;
   ++gradeCounter;'

Comment: probably this code have problem..

Comment: `Introduction to Java Programming!!

Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100
Type the end-of-file indicator to terminate input:
    On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <Ctrl>d then press Enter
    On Windows type <Ctrl>z then press Enter
90
^Z
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at GradeBook.inputGrades(GradeBook.java:52)
 at GradeBookTest.main(GradeBookTest.java:12)`  <-console

Answer (score 0):

Check the following thing and also check whether you are respecting the rules:

```
public int nextInt()
```

**Throws:**
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

For more details about **next** method visit:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Switch case in the above program then give a space between switch and condition.

Dont write like this --> switch(n)
Write like this --> switch (n)